# Why "d:\0.0" doesn't substring of "D:\0.0" while using "findstr" command of Windows command prompt

Tags: command-line, cmd, findstr

I'm using "findstr" command with **case-insensitive** option (/I flag),
and I can't explain the results below.

```
echo "D:\0.0" | findstr /I "d:\0"
```

Output: "D:\0.0"

```
echo "D:\0.0" | findstr /I "d:\0.0"
```

Output:

why *"d:\0.0"* doesn't substring of *"D:\0.0"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are searching for a regexp rather than a substring:

```
>echo "D:\0.0" | findstr /I "D:\0.0"
```

gives nothing either. You want to add the literal flag `/l`

```
>echo "D:\0.0" | findstr /I /l "d:\0.0"
```

gives:

```
"D:\0.0"
```

If you want to use the regexp, you need to escape the dot

```
>echo "D:\0.0" | findstr /I "d:\0\.0"
```

Comment: I am wondering why you need to escape the dot instead of the backslash?? (ie, why your last example works... But escaping the backslash works too, and that one I understand : `echo "D:\0.0" | findstr /I "d:\\0.0"` ... I don't undestand how escaping the dot helps ^^ It should match "any" character, including a dot. Please explain! [I know escaping the dot forces it to match "only" a dot. But why it helps to bypass the interpretation of "\0", I don't understand...)

Comment: windows' interpretation of \ only treats it as an escape character if it is followed by a metacharacter like `$`, so `\0` matches `\0` not the null character.

Comment: @OliverMatthews: If that is so (`\0` matches `\0`), and as `.` matches anything (even a regular dot), then why `echo "D:\0.0" | findstr /I "D:\0.0"` didn't match ??  I'm quite a bit puzzled here (and I use regexps everyday ^^). To me, that regexp implementation looks flawed (And about `\0` : "usually" (but there are many regexp variants), `\x` matches `x`, not only when `x` is a special metacharacter... to match `\x` you usually write `\\x`, or `\\\x` if x is a special metacharacter)